# Visual Studio keeps handle on folder opened during debug session

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2017, locking

My application opens an XML file in a folder to deserialize its contents. I release everything, but devenv still keeps a handle on the containing folder. Problem is: I open 3rd-party programs as child processes and their execution will fail, since they moan about not being able to delete the folder.

This is the code I use in my application to open the file and deserialize the XML contents:

```
XmlConfig result = null;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlConfig));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        result = (XmlConfig)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}

return result;
```

Before, I didn't use the `FileStream` but only the `StreamReader`, but the result was the same.

The error occurs, if:

- I start the debug session from within Visual Studio
- I run the application from the output folder and attach the debugger before running the code above
- I run the application from the output folder and do not attach the debugger, but the error occurred before

The error does not occur, if:

- I run the application from the output folder without attaching any debugger
- I run the application from the output folder and attach the debugger after running the code above

I'm running VS Professional 2017 15.8.4. as administrator (since the application has to run with admin privileges) It's a WPF project, .Net version 4.6.

All I could find on this topic is about not being able to build because of Visual Studio locking some dll file in the `bin` or `obj` folder. That doesn't match my problem.

**What happens here and more important: how can I solve that problem?**

**Edit:**

Here's the error message I get from my child process:

```
devenx.exe   pid: 8612   type: file   1388: C:\lockedfolder
```

I also checked that with [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker):

[image: unlocker showing the folder is locked by devenv.exe]

Comment: I think it would help to see the error as well

Comment: Are you sure it's the `devenv.exe` process that keeps the handle? Did you check it with the Process Monitor tool?

Comment: try moving the xmlSerializer into the Streamreader's using block. Maybe it keeps a handle open. And also try flushing and closing the stream explicitly. This shouldn't be necessary but worth trying before digging deeper.

Comment: The child process tells me, it's devenv.exe. I also checked that with Unlocker. I'll add the error message to the post.

Comment: @RobinB I tried different combinations of where to put `fs.Flush()` and `fs.Close()` (since I've never had to use them, the `using`s were always sufficient) and I guess it works now. I've got to make some more test to verify, though. I ended up, putting `fs.Flush()` within the `Streamreader`'s `using` without explicitly closing the `FileStream`. Putting the `Flush` after the inner using gave me an exception à la `cannot flush a stream that has been closed.`. Would you make an answer from you comment so I can accept it after my additional tests?

Answer (score 1):

So as I was asked to I'm gonna formulate my comment as an answer.
Big disclaimer: this problem in itself still remains a mistery to me as I couldn't to my best efforts reproduce it in any form.

I threw together a little test program:

#### Example

```
class Program
{
    public static string filepath = "test.xml";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serialize();

        Console.WriteLine(Deserialize().Test);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static XmlConfig Deserialize()
    {
        XmlConfig result = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlConfig));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                result = (XmlConfig)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void Serialize()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlConfig));
            serializer.Serialize(fs, new XmlConfig());
        }
    }
}

public class XmlConfig
{
    public string Test { get; set; } = "Teststring";
}
```

This should not have worked if the problem was in the code. But it did execute fine without any problems. Debug/Release, with/without attached debugger, VS as Admin/Non-Admin.

#### Advices

So here are my advices which seemed to help solve the question which I always recommend trying when working with streams/serialization:

- Even though Streams like `FileStream` implement `IDisposable` and should flush+close the stream when used in a `using`-block try to manually flush and or close them. This can sometimes do the trick (especially when working with COM-Ports)
- Always try to restrict local variables to the smallest scope possible (i.e. move Serializer initialization inside the using it is needed.
- Less configuration > more configuration that goes along with reducing complexity as much as possible (For this compare `Serialize()` and `Deserialize()` in my example)